# Prime number optimization

Tags: ruby, math

Below is a prime number calculator I've been working on. Currently it can calculate 100,000 prime numbers in about 22 seconds on my computer. Any thoughts on how to make the below program quicker programatically or mathematically?

```
include Math

print "How many prime numbers do you want?:"
x = gets.chomp.to_i #want x primes
c = 0 #want c primes
t = 3 #test number
d = 1 #divisor
n = 0 #current number of divisors

puts "2"
c+=1
while c < x
    while n <= 1 && d <= Math.sqrt(t) 
        if(t % d == 0)
            n+=1
            d+=2
        else
            d+=2
        end
    end

    if(n == 1)
        c+=1
        puts "#{t}"
    end
    t+=2
    d = 1
    n = 0
end
```

Comment: This question would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you just want hi-speed. Use `require 'prime'; Prime.prime?(x)`

Comment: My comment isn't about performance, but might interest you: your code is not very ruby-like, that is, does not follow the best principles in ruby that differs a lot from other languages. For instance, you should name your variables to what they mean, not write comments next to their names. Instead of `c = 0 #want c primes`, do `number_of_primes = 0`. Also, avoid `while` and `for` loops at all costs, opting for more functional operations, like arrays `.each`, `.map`; prefer inline `if`s if possible; etc.

Comment: You want a prime number generating sieve, see [generating primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving running code, which is a better fit on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast way to find all primes up to N (or the first n primes) is to use what's called a sieve.  The idea is you start with a list of integers 2,... M and associate with each either a boolean value of True, or integer 1.  Then starting with 2, make every multiple of 2 (bigger than 2) false (or zero).  None of these are prime because they are all divisible by 2.  Then, in your list, find the next smallest value that still has True (3 in this case).  Then, set all multiples of 3 (bigger than 3) to False.  Then repeat.  Find the next smallest number in the list that is still marked True.  (4 was marked false because it was a multple of 2), 5 is the next choice.  Repeat, repeat, repeat... until the smallest one you find is bigger than sqrt(M).  Then every value in your list with True is a prime.  This will be asymptotically much much faster than what your code does (for every value try to find a divisor).